# on the classification of groups of order $p^4$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Burnside, in his book "Theory of Groups of Finite Order" (see http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/40395) classify all the groups of order $p^4$ (see pages 100-102).
My question is in regard to the group (xv) in the odd case.
For $p>3$ its nicest description (in my opinion) is as follows
$$G=(\mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p)\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_p,$$
where the action is by 
\begin{equation}
k=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 &1
\end{array} \right)
\in GL_3(\mathbb{F}_p).
\end{equation}
It is not hard to see that for $p=2$ there is no such group.
However, as far as I can tell it should exist for $p=3$ but I couldnt find it in Burnside classificaition.

I will be happy if anyone can clerify this point.

Comment: Yes it exists for $p=3$, but is isomorphic to one of the other groups on the list. I think it's isomorphic to (xi).

Comment: Derek Holt- In (xi) there is an element (P in Burnside notations) such that $C_G(P)=\langle P \rangle$. I don't think such an element exist in the group in my question. Furthermore, why did Burnside distinguish the $p=3$ case from the other cases if it exist?

Comment: When $p=3$ in Group (xv), the element $SR$ has order $9$ and $\langle SR \rangle$ is self-centralizing. When $p>3$, Group (xv) has exponent $p$, which distinguishes it from when $p=3$.

Comment: Thanks, just to be clear, the group which correspond to the group in my question in your opinion is the group (xi) and not the group (xv) in the $p=3$ case?.

Comment: That's right! I have now done an isomorphism test on the computer, and it's definitely (xi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group (xiv) in Burnside's list exists for $p=3$, but it is isomorphic to the group numbered (xi) - I checked that by computer.

Group (xiv) has exponent $9$ when $p=3$, but exponent $p$ for $p>3$.

Comment: Derek Holt- I think you mean the group (xv) and not (xiv). Accepted anyway.